# Curve in D3 shape

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I tried creating a funnel chart using D3 and vx. This is what i have achieved so far

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L-TDMSWHUS-ZOi0jb8t

But i tried all curve options from d3-shape. But couldn't create the cure as shown in [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like your best bet would be to make a basic area chart and to reflect it across the x-axis. I believe that would give a similar effect. For more clarification, the x-axis would go through the horizontal center of the chart in the image above.

Comment: @pytth Yes. I fixed it just now. Removed the multiple line-paths and added single line path which fixed the issue. The curves are working as expected. It was my mistake :(

Comment: @sathis so you solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your best bet would be to make a basic area chart and to reflect it across the x-axis. I believe that would give a similar effect. For more clarification, the x-axis would go through the horizontal center of the chart in the image above